# IOS When I press leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem at the same time, UINavigationViewController has odd behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c

As the title describes, when I press the two `UIBarButtonItems` at the same time, the `UINavigationBar`'s title is overlapped by another `UIViewController`'s title, and the view stack also behave in an unexpected way.
I think this issue is caused by pushing and popping `UIViewController` at the same time, what can I do to solve this problem, can I prevent pressing the two button(in fact they are not) at the same time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: The default value of this property is NO. i dont think this is the issue. [reference link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html)

Comment: Yes,it is.
@property(nonatomic,getter=isMultipleTouchEnabled) BOOL multipleTouchEnabled;   // default is NO
@property(nonatomic,getter=isExclusiveTouch) BOOL       exclusiveTouch;         // default is NO
but property [exclusiveTouch] seems what i need. Thanks all the same. @Igor Matyushkin,@pawan

Comment: well, [self.navigationController.navigationBar setExclusiveTouch:YES]; failed

Answer (score 0):

Not a recommended approach but, you can use a variable to return the control back from the selector you don't want to consider at this point. The selector that gets called first will be executed and set variable to `false` once the other button will sense the touch and try to execute the flag will help to simply `return`.

Comment: Thank you NeverHopeless, this is what I want to do to solve this issue, but I encounter some troubles when handling the leftBarButtonItem's method.

Comment: What is the trouble ?

Comment: Change leftBarButtonItem's action does not work, but if you custom the leftBarButtonItem it will lost the arrowed button style.

Comment: Without getting a whole picture it is hard to predict. Please explain the whole scenario which button you have in controller nav bar (custom or default).What do you want custom or default. a snap shot would be a plus. I guess right now you are talking about back button of nav bar.. correct ?